Uniqueness of charge distribution in conductor
I found out about a result describing the uniqueness of the charge distribution on a conductor. It says that for a given total charge on a conductor and a given charge distribution of the outside (outside universe) of the conductor, there is one and only one way to distribute the charges on the surface of the conductor, such that the field everywhere inside the conductor is zero.
I have heard of the uniqueness theorems but I am unable to see how they lead to this. The theorems seem to guarantee uniqueness of the field and the potential in a given region given the charge distribution, but here, we want to show that given the net charge on the conductor and given the external charge configuration (i.e. outside the conductor), the charge distribution on the surface is unique. How can we prove this result?

you also need to specify the net charge on the conductor for it to be unique.

@QPhysl sorry, missed that toward the end... edited the question

@Nf23kdr by outside charge distribution I mean there are some charges outside the conductor... it is not isolated... yes, they produce their own field.

If you assume that the charge is all distributed on the surface of the conductor then your boundary conditions (derived from Maxwell's equations) give you a relation for the surface charge density which is unique. That is, in SI units:
$$\left(\nabla V_\mathrm{above}-\nabla V_\mathrm{below}\right)\cdot\mathbf{\hat{n}}=-\frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0}$$
If you don't make this assumption, then there are other ways to prove it. There are more elegant proofs but the first that comes to mind is that we are asking if $\nabla^2V=-\rho/\varepsilon_0$ has a unique $\rho$ when we specify $V$. This is the Poisson equation and the Laplace operator can be expressed in the form of an operator in Sterm-Liouville theory which means that the solutions of it can be expressed as a complete basis (note that it isn't an overcomplete basis). Next by reconstructing the $V(\mathbf{r})$ that we have we get a unique $\rho$ because the basis isn't overcomplete. This requires that $V(\mathbf{r})$ is specified everywhere. See Sterm-Liouville theory and Green's functions
